# Set Prop Key Dynamically JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following in JSX (this code does not work, just an example of what I'm trying to do):

```
const propKey = 'someProp';
const jsx = <MyComponent [propKey]="some value" />;
// evaluates to <MyComponent someProp="some value">
```

I'm using babel es2015 stage-1, so I could spread a dictionary like this:

```
const extraProps = {[propKey]: 'some value'};
const jsx = <MyComponent {...extraProps} />
```

but that seems too clunky for just one prop. I'm not looking to use React.createElement; all my classes are es6 classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create in the JSX an object using the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), and spread it:

```
const propKey = 'someProp';
const jsx = <MyComponent { ...{ [propKey]: "some value" } } />;
```

Answer (score 3):

JSX is syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement`. So one solution is to call `React.createElement` directly:

```
const element = React.createElement(MyComponent, {[propKey]: 'some value'});
```